# When drawing on multiple videos with opencv I get this error.?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video-streaming, object-detection

I am trying to draw bounding boxes on multiple video captured streams. I got this error after changing the code below to allow it to be in a for loop ( not sure if that works in the first place).

I have been advised to put the video captured data into a numpy array instead of a list to avoid the error but I'm not sure about that.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera\social_distance_detector.py", line 119, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
[Finished in 5.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera\social_distance_detector.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;d:\Program Files\Git\cmd;d:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;d:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

happens in this block:

```
for frame) in streams:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 5, color, 1)
```

I found an advice on the internet to prase int the args like this:

```
for frame in streams:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, int(startX, startY), int(endX, endY), color, 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 5, color, 1)
```

but I got this error instead:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera\social_distance_detector.py", line 119, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame, int(startX, startY), int(endX, endY), color, 2)
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0
[Finished in 2.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera\social_distance_detector.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;d:\Program Files\Git\cmd;d:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;d:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Library\bin;d:\Users\abdul\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%;C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

I'm a noob so ill put the full code after this line just in case it helps

```
# USAGE
# python social_distance_detector.py --input pedestrians.mp4
# python social_distance_detector.py --input pedestrians.mp4 --output output.avi

# import the necessary packages
from TheLazyCoder import social_distancing_config as config
from TheLazyCoder.detection import detect_people
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", type=str, default="",
    help="path to (optional) input video file")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, default="",
    help="path to (optional) output video file")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--display", type=int, default=1,
    help="whether or not output frame should be displayed")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the COCO class labels our YOLO model was trained on
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([config.MODEL_PATH, "coco.names"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

# derive the paths to the YOLO weights and model configuration
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([config.MODEL_PATH, "yolov3.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join([config.MODEL_PATH, "yolov3.cfg"])

# load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

# check if we are going to use GPU
if config.USE_GPU:
    # set CUDA as the preferable backend and target
    print("[INFO] setting preferable backend and target to CUDA...")
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

# determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# initialize the video stream and pointer to output video file
print("[INFO] accessing video stream...")
vs =[ 
cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW),
cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
]

writer = None

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # read the next frame from the file
    streams=[]
    for cap in vs:
        grabbed, frame = cap.read()
        streams.append([grabbed, frame])


    

    # if the frame was not grabbed, then we have reached the end
    # of the stream
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame and then detect people (and only people) in it
    
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)
    results = detect_people(frame, net, ln,
        personIdx=LABELS.index("person"))

    # initialize the set of indexes that violate the minimum social
    # distance
    violate = set()

    # ensure there are *at least* two people detections (required in
    # order to compute our pairwise distance maps)
    if len(results) >= 2:
        # extract all centroids from the results and compute the
        # Euclidean distances between all pairs of the centroids
        centroids = np.array([r[2] for r in results])
        D = dist.cdist(centroids, centroids, metric="euclidean")

        # loop over the upper triangular of the distance matrix
        for i in range(0, D.shape[0]):
            for j in range(i + 1, D.shape[1]):
                # check to see if the distance between any two
                # centroid pairs is less than the configured number
                # of pixels
                if D[i, j] < config.MIN_DISTANCE:
                    # update our violation set with the indexes of
                    # the centroid pairs
                    violate.add(i)
                    violate.add(j)

    # loop over the results
    for (i, (prob, bbox, centroid)) in enumerate(results):
        # extract the bounding box and centroid coordinates, then
        # initialize the color of the annotation
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = bbox
        (cX, cY) = centroid
        color = (0, 255, 0)

        # if the index pair exists within the violation set, then
        # update the color
        if i in violate:
            color = (0, 0, 255)

        # draw (1) a bounding box around the person and (2) the
        # centroid coordinates of the person,
        for frame in streams:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, int(startX, startY), int(endX, endY), color, 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 5, color, 1)

    # draw the total number of social distancing violations on the
    # output frame
    for frame in streams:
        text = "Social Distancing Violations: {}".format(len(violate))
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, frame.shape[0] - 25),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.85, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    # check to see if the output frame should be displayed to our
    # screen
    for number, (grabbed, frame) in enumerate(streams):
        if args["display"] > 0:
        # show the output frame
            cv2.imshow(f'Cam {number}', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # if an output video file path has been supplied and the video
    # writer has not been initialized, do so now
    if args["output"] != "" and writer is None:
        # initialize our video writer
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(args["output"], fourcc, 25,
            (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)

    # if the video writer is not None, write the frame to the output
    # video file
    if writer is not None:
        writer.write(frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get your startX, startY, endX, endY from bbox. We don't know what bbox looks like since the detect_people function isn't show here. The error you're getting is saying that one of those values, startX, startY, endX, endY is probably a tuple rather than a single number. Just to check, print out all four values before you call cv2.rectangle. Also, I think you misinterpreted the int casting advice. It should look like this:

```py
cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(startX), int(startY)), (int(endX), int(endY)), color, 2)
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for explaining. so I added a print line like you asked and i got this out put158 352 445 520
162 353 447 521
203 352 473 521
155 355 452 520
161 353 445 520
158 356 454 520

Comment: after every four set of numbers, it drops to a new line.

Comment: what was the last line it printed before it gave you the TypeError?

Comment: [INFO] loading YOLO from disk...
[INFO] accessing video stream...
53 143 668 520
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\PythonProjects\Social-distance-detection-mastera\social_distance_detector.py", line 117, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
[Finished in 3.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas. That line looks perfectly fine, so does the output. I copy/pasted the line into my program and it works as expected. The only other thing I can think of is maybe you're using a very old version of OpenCV and the parameters for cv2.rectangle has changed? What's your OpenCV version?

Comment: thank you but I just decided to use a player to switch between screens since this was too much trouble. thank you though.